# How to test thread safety of a class from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on thread safe singleton class and I know below code is not thread safe because I am making a double check locking error.

```
protected static TestSingleton instance;

private TestSingleton() {
    // some code
}

public static synchronized void setup() {
    if (instance == null) {
        TestSingleton holder = new TestSingleton();
        instance = holder;
    }
}

public static TestSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        setup();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

But I am trying to test this out so that I can prove it programmatically that this is not thread safe class. This is for my learning experience.

How can I test this programmatically and prove it is not thread safe?

Comment: You can't prove programmatically that a code is thread safe - the code may actually always work fine on your combination of JVM/CPU architecture/OS. You can only *hope* that a test will find the problem.

Comment: If you run it on an x86/hotspot you will probably not be able to make it fail. That does not mean it is safe and it may break in Java 9 or on SPARC or ... Thread (un-)safety is proven by applying the rules of the JLS.

Comment: Ask skeptics to construct a proof that it *is* thread-safe, given the Java Language Specification. The problem that I see is that a thread calling `getInstance()` might "see" a non-null value assigned to `instance` before that value is fully constructed. The reading thread never encounters a memory barrier in that case. If they are so confident it's safe, they should be eager to shoulder the burden of proof.

Comment: No, there's no guarantee it will fail. But if you follow the rules, and can articulate them, you can be sure it won't fail. Why is this even an issue? Why not use a correct mechanism? Who's so wedded to this particular implementation and why?

Answer (score 4):

It comes down to this:  Your program has some number of threads, running on some number of processors, but your computer only has *one* main memory.

Each thread is going to read and write different memory locations in some order, somewhat independently of what other threads are doing; and all of those reads and writes have to be *serialized* as they go out to the memory.  That is to say, the memory system has to perform those reads and writes one-by-one.

For any given execution of a multi-threaded program, there can be myriad different ways that the operations of the different threads could be serialized.  Literally, too many to count.  If even one of those possible serializations causes your program to produce wrong output, then your program is not thread safe.

So how can you test them all?

You can't.  There are too many of them, and serializations that might happen frequently on one computer (e.g., your customer's mission critical server) might *never* happen on some other computer (e.g., your test harness.)

The only way to insure thread safety is to use mathematically proven algorithms to synchronize the action of your threads so that bad interleavings can not happen.

Comment: Not thread safe because some thread, A, could call `getInstance()` and find `instance != null`, and never synchronize with thread B---the thread that created the singleton.  With no synchronization, there's no guarantee that thread A's view of memory will be consistent with thread B's view.  In particular, thread A could, in theory, see the singleton object in a partially initialized or uninitialized state even though it sees that `instance` has been set.  Google for "java happens before" to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **you can't.**

No matter how much times you run this code in a test environment, there is a non-zero probability of it actually working right.
The problem is, you can't really estimate this probability and therefore can't find a number of test runs required for the probability of them showing correct result to be close to 1.

**But** you can actually reason about how a given program *may* be executed. Finding a way for a multithreaded program to break is usually easier than proving it can never break.

In this exact case there is the following problem: *write* to `instance` during the `setup` execution in Thread 1 is not in a happens-before relationship with the *read* from `instance` performed to return a value from `getInstance` execution in Thread 2, nor with the *read* from `instance` performed to check against null in `setup` execution in Thread 2. That means that two calls from different threads might yield different results, that is, the implementation is broken and we didn't even start thinking about code reordering.

Establishing such a relationship by, for example, declaring the `instance` to be *volatile* would fix it.

You can learn more about sequential consistency, program order and happens-before relationship in [this excellent paper about Java Memory Model](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/) by Alexey Shipilev. This will help you immensely.

Unfortunately, automation of said reasoning is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen why my below response is incorrect. Please see the related comment thread as to why.

<strike>I do not think it is possible to show that your program is not thread safe in its current incarnation, as the logic inside of the methods is 'safe' enough.</strike>

This is due to the fact that, even though the setup() call inside of getInstance() might be attempted to be invoked simultaneously, the logic inside setup() will occur synchronously due the method being declared as synchronized.

Imagine you have two threads, A and B, competing for access to the setup(). A goes first and sets the reference to the TestSingleton object in the instance variable. While A was inside of the setup() method, B attempts to invoke it and is blocked. A finishes up, and B enters the method. Since instance is now not null, none of the logic in setup() is invoked by B. Therefore, you will never see multiple invocations of the logic inside of the conditional block in setup().

Comment: Problem here that `new TestSingleton()` is not atomic. and can be optimized by first acquiring memory, assigning `instance` value and only then invocation of constructor body. It can lead to some thread can see `TestSingleton` in not initialized state

Comment: @talex the synchronized method creates a happens-before relationship, so any threads that enter it after it has been entered once should see a fully-constructed TestSingleton object. Am I missing something in my analysis?

Comment: @Andonaeus yes: the second thread might see the instance as non null in getInstance, and thus *not* enter the synchronized setup method. So you don't have a happens-before relationship.

Comment: @JBNizet In that case, everything is fine, as the resource has already been initialized; I do not see the issue. 

In the case of the second thread seeing it as null while the first thread is initializing it, the second thread will block on the synchroned setup() call until the first thread is done. When the first thread finishes, the second thread will enter setup(), see that the resource is NOT null (due to the happens-before relationship), and do nothing. Even in this case, everything is fine.

Comment: The problem, AFAIK, is that the instance might not be fully-constructed yet, due to reordering.

Comment: So it would not be guaranteed to be fully-constructed (not null) after the first thread exits the synchronized method block and the second thread enters it, even though the method is synchronized?

Comment: Essentially, I am almost positive that the object is guaranteed to be fully constructed once the first thread exits the synchronized block. Yes, the JVM can reorder the assignment of the newly-created object to the variable and the construction of said variable, but both MUST be completed before exiting the synchronized block due to the happens-before nature of it.

Comment: The happens-before is only guaranteed if the second thread reads the assigned value from a synchronized block. But getInstance() is not synchronized. It reads the value and then skips the synchronized setup method if it sees a non-null value.

Comment: @JBNizet Ahh now I see what I was missing. Thanks for bearing with me there!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely things for you to look for via a test such as you describe is two threads obtaining different instances of `TestSingleton` from its `getInstance()` method, or a thread getting a `null` return value from that method, or a thread returning an instance before it is fully initialized.

The problem is that you cannot be certain how likely any of those is to occur, and indeed, they are probably very *unlikely*.  You might run a very large number of iterations of a test without ever seeing any of those failure behaviors.  If you *do* see one of them then you will have proven the program to not be thread-safe, but not seeing any of them proves nothing.

Thread safety is a program property that you must prove by analysis of the program.  It cannot be proven by testing in finite time.

Comment: @user1950349, any analysis of Java synchronization must ultimately be built on the requirements on the Java memory model, as presented in [chapter 17 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html).  This is by no means an easy read.  It might be easier to present some of the *many* credible explanations available on the web for why double-checked locking in Java is broken.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're right. I must add that for gaining an entry-level understanding of Java Memory Model there's a very nice article by Alexey Shipilev which I linked in my answer.